# How to get parent and child name in taxonomy page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have new taxonomy "`car-brand`" and I want to show name of parent taxonomy in child taxonomy page.

My hierarchical taxonomy:

```
bmw
  -series1
    --F20
    --G40
  -series2 
    --F22
    --G42
benz
  -Aclass 
    --W176
    --W177
  -Cclass
    --W203
    --W204
```

For example, when user is in `F20` taxonomy page I want show this with url:

```
brand: BMW {level 1 taxonomy}
series: series1 {level 2 taxonomy}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_ancestors()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/) to get an array of IDs of the ancestors of a term in any taxonomies, and in your case, you would use the *last* 2 items like the example below, where I used:

- [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) to get the ID of the term on the **term archive page** that you are currently viewing
- [`get_term_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_field/) to get the term's name, but you can use [`get_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) instead
- [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) to get the URL of the term's archive page

```php
// Get the current term ID.
$cat_id = get_queried_object_id();

// Get the term's ancestors.
$parents = get_ancestors( $cat_id, 'car-brand' );

// Get the level 1 ancestor term, and display it.
$brand_cat_id = array_pop( $parents );
printf(
    'brand: <a href="%s">%s</a><br />',
    esc_url( get_term_link( $brand_cat_id ) ),
    esc_html( get_term_field( 'name', $brand_cat_id ) )
);

// Get the level 2 ancestor term, and display it.
$series_cat_id = array_pop( $parents );
printf(
    'series: <a href="%s">%s</a>',
    esc_url( get_term_link( $series_cat_id ) ),
    esc_html( get_term_field( 'name', $series_cat_id ) )
);
```